# HighStock data line disappears in IE8 if zoomed into a small period

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

I have encountered a problem in HighStock chart.
My x axis is date. If I set the navigator to a very tight range, the line disappears in IE8.
It works well in IE9 and FF though.

```
this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
                    1321008645000, 1321008655000, null, false, {
                        trigger: 'rangeSelectorInput'
                    });
```

See the fiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/adagent007/MJBtG/13/

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is known bug reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1394 so I suggest to stay on track with this thread.